# C# User already exist error when it was not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm running into a strange issue on my high traffic website that usually occurs after every day or two. I have a payment form where I'm asking the user to create login at the same time (if they previously don't).

My application developed on `ASP.NET MVC` and using the `Membership` for User Management. This is a piece of code that is on the top of `MVC Action` before processing a payment

```
if (!IsUserLoggedIn())
{
   var isUserExist = _userService.GetUserByName(model.NewUser.UserName) != null;
   if (isUserExist)
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName Already Exist");
      return View();
   }
}

private bool IsUserLoggedIn()
{
    return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

And this is how my data access code look like

```
public EditUser GetUserByName(string userName)
{
    var user = DataContext.aspnet_Users
                 .Join(DataContext.aspnet_Membership,
                    u => u.UserId,
                    m => m.UserId,
                    (u, m) => new { User = u, Membership = m })

                 .SingleOrDefault(s => s.User.UserName == userName &&
                                        s.User.UserId ==    s.Membership.UserId);

    if(user!=null)
    {
       return new EditUser(....);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem is when someone is not already logged in on my site and come to Payment page and tries to create his login. When form submit, the error message return "UserName Already Exist" when it was actually not. Meaning that, this new user haven't already exist in the database but the above piece of code still indicate that user already exist which is really strange.

Comment: Does it not just show that the _name_ exists? It may not be the same user.

Comment: Why the join to membership table?  Don't you just want to query on `AspNet_Users.UserName` to see if it already exists?

Comment: @stuartd That is the problem. User is different and entered a username that is not previously exist in our database.; But they still get the error saying "user already exist"

Comment: @steamrolla That is just for double checking to make sure no record is dangling in `AspNet_Users` table. I also tried with Memebership API by doing something like ` Membership.FindUsersByName()` but no success

Comment: Assuming you can't reproduce this, maybe you need to add some logging to try and track down what the issue is.

Comment: @stuartd Yes, I believe it should. Most of the time it works. This seems to be happen after every day or two. So really not sure what's going wrong

Comment: @steamrolla is right in saying you dont need to join on to membership table, if your usernames are unique, then `DataContext.aspnet_Users
 .SingleOrDefault(s => s.User.UserName == userName);` should be enough, seems something wring with your query.

Comment: @PreetSingh I can but don't think that really matters. It's just double checking if the associated user also exist in `Membership` table. I will try to put some `logging` statement but any idea what could be the possible reason by looking the code.